# An identity involving binomial coefficients and rational functions

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

While going through some exercises in my analysis textbook, I came up with an equation which looks like an identity. I strongly believe that this is the case, but I couldn't prove this.

> $$\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-1)^k\frac{p}{k+p}\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+p}{p}^{-1}$$

Can someone provide a proof of this identity? Also, it would help a lot if you could explain the general strategy of proving such identities, if there is one, for me. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Multiply through by $\dbinom{n+p}{p}$. Rewrite $\dfrac{p}{k+p} \dbinom{n+p}{p} \dbinom{n}{k}$ as $\dbinom{n+p}{n-k} \dbinom{k+p-1}{p-1}$. Thus, the left hand side becomes $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^k \dbinom{n+p}{n-k} \dbinom{k+p-1}{p-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right)^{n-k} \dbinom{n+p}{k} \dbinom{n-k+p-1}{p-1}$ $ = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+p-1} \left(-1\right)^{n-k} \dbinom{n+p}{k} \dbinom{n-k+p-1}{p-1}$ (we extended the sum by addends that are $0$). Now you have (up to sign) the $\left(n+p\right)$-th finite difference of the ...

Comment: ... degree-$\left(p-1\right)$-polynomial $\dbinom{n-X+p-1}{p-1}$ before you, except that it's missing its very last addend (for $k = n+p$), which, unlike the other addends we have inserted, is not $0$. Now, $n+p > p-1$, so draw your conclusions.

Comment: The same identity appears in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193611/binomial-coefficient-identity .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general strategy is to introduce a variable $x$ and then to deal with some polynomials and/or other power series, of which your expression is a value at $x=1$.

In you case it goes along these lines:
$$\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-1)^k\frac{p}{k+p}\binom{n}{k}=F(1),\text{ where} \\
F(x)=\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-1)^kx^{k+p}\frac{p}{k+p}\binom{n}{k}$$

The power was chosen out of the blue, so that the function would simplify a little when we take a *derivative*.
$$F'(x)=p\cdot\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-1)^kx^{k+p-1}\binom{n}{k}=p\cdot x^{p-1}\sum_{0\leq k\leq n}(-x)^k\binom{n}{k}=p\,x^{p-1}(1-x)^n$$

Together with the obvious $F(0)=0$ and the knowledge of [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), this gives us the way to reconstruct the desired $F(1)$:
$$F(1)=\int\limits_0^1F'(x)dx=p\int\limits_0^1x^{p-1}(1-x)^ndx=p\cdot B(p,n+1)=\\
=p\cdot{(p-1)!\;n!\over(n+p)!}={p!\;n!\over(n+p)!}=\binom{n+p}{p}^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

This  identity has  appeared on  MSE on  several occasions  in various
forms. There  is a proof using  residues which goes like  this (quoted
from what should be earlier posts).  Start with the function

$$f(z) = n! (-1)^n \frac{p}{z+p} \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

We then get

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z) =
n! (-1)^n \frac{p}{k+p}
\prod_{q=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q} \prod_{q=k+1}^n \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = n! (-1)^n \frac{p}{k+p} \frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
= (-1)^k \frac{p}{k+p} {n\choose k}.$$

Residues sum to zero and hence we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{p}{k+p} {n\choose k}
= - \mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) - \mathrm{Res}_{z=-p} f(z).$$

Observe that $\lim_{R\to\infty} 2\pi R/R/R^{n+1}  = 0$ and the residue
at infinity is zero. It remains to compute

$$- \mathrm{Res}_{z=-p} f(z) =  
- n! (-1)^n \times p \times \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{-p-q}
\\ = n! \times p \times \prod_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{p+q}
= n! \times p \times \frac{(p-1)!}{(p+n)!}
= {n+p\choose p}^{-1}.$$

This concludes the argument. Here we require that $-p$ not be among the poles in $[0,n],$ resulting in a singularity in the sum.